# ksh - Display Current Mode

Tags: shell, ksh

Is there any way to have ksh display the current typing mode at the bottom of the window like vim; like "Insert", "Command", "Visual", etc? Unfortunately, I am having a lot of trouble remembering which mode I'm in and find the shell unintuitive (at least until I get used to all the commands). I consistantly hit the wrong key in command mode and have difficulty figuring out how to get back to proper typing (sometimes it lets me type but not delete part of the line and I don't know why).

I am required to use ksh for work and am heavily restricted in what I can download and install, but I need to figure this out. Hopefully there is something I can do with a profile or script along these lines to help ease the transistion. Also, this is HP-Unix, in case that affects anything.

Comment: You could try ````set -o emacs```` and use emacs command-line editing, which is not modal.

Answer (score 1):

This `set -o` alone command will show if `emacs` is defined to `on`

---

```
$ set -o|grep emacs
emacs            on
```